# Spacing of text in align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

I have a problem, when i type the following code the 'From Equation 1' appears in the middle of the line but I want it at the edge to line up with (2). I have tried h spacing it but it did not work. Any other suggestions?

```
In the case of the dot product we then have
    \begin{align}\label{eq:2}
    \left\lVert\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert
    & = \sqrt{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}}
    && \text{(from Equation \eqref{eq:1})}\nonumber\\[0.2em]
    & = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}
 \end{align}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\tag` macro may be what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\tag' macro and 'align' env.
\begin{document}
In the case of the dot product we then have
\begin{align}\label{eq:2}
    \left\lVert\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert
    &= \sqrt{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} \cdot
             \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}}
       \tag{from Equation \eqref{eq:1}}\\[1ex]
    &= \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```